# Does Unity 2d support lenses?

Tags: unity-2d, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would a Unity lens written for Unity 3D also work in Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38904/would-a-unity-lens-written-for-unity-3d-also-work-in-unity-2d)

Does Unity 2d support lenses and scopes?

If not, are there any plans to support them in the future?